# How to create rating bars in Android?

Tags: android, rating

I need to create rating bars like in Google Play as follows:

[image]

Do I have to manually create all of this, or is there an already implemented solution?

p.s. the built in RatingBar looks awful and does not work as expected.

Comment: you can style the rating bar, to look different. you could also check for existing libraries.

Comment: If you're talking about just a bar of stars to rate something, use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html. If you're refering to the whole five lines with stars and a graph, you'll need to implement that yourself.

Comment: That would be annoying to create all these custom rating bars by myself. Also I could not find any useful libraries. If any of you have some reference, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two libraries that will help you:

https://github.com/railskarthi/Ratingbar

And a more custom Rating Bar:

https://github.com/badoo/StarBar

Last one can set colors easily and has a lot of listeners.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do complex designs such as the Google play ratings, then there are no existing libraries at present. But for starting a simple rating bar [Rating Bar documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html) for the same.